# xfree86: configuration of the sound mixer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x-windows, media-keys

I am running Ubuntu 9.04 and I use a Logitech MX-5000 keyboard. The mediakeys on this keyboard where setup (auto-magically) with xfree86  (XF86VolumeUp, X86VolumeDown etc.).

Now, I have changed from using my bluetooth headset to using my speakers *but* the mediakeys still only control the headset volume.

So, the question is:  how can I configure the sound mixer that xfree86 uses for VolumeUp and VolumeDown ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...found it:

System -> Preferences -> Sound -> Devices -> Default Mixer Tracks.